# Cannot add application back to My Facebook Page after deleting it from that page

Tags: facebook

The process to recreate this is:

1. Go to an Application Profile Page.
2. Click "Add to My Page" on the bottom left of the Application Profile Page.
3. Go to the Facebook Page the application was added to.
4. On the left side of that Facebook Page click "Edit" and remove the application from the page
5. Go back to the Application Profile Page and try to repeat the process.

I'm not sure if anybody else has this issue or if there's some sort of an option I'm not seeing but if the application gets removed from the Facebook Page I am unable to re-add it and I have to create a whole new application within Facebook in order to add it back to the page. Has anybody run into this problem and/or solved it with some sort of setting in Facebook?

Comment: What is the application?  Stuff gets deprecated at Facebook at an alarming pace.  When that happens it doesn't get deleted untill you remove it from your page.  Was it the FBML app?

Comment: It's an iFrame app and doesn't use any facebook functionality within it. It's just displaying data.

Comment: After I looked at I could tell.  I do know they started enforcing the new oauth today and are requiring all developers to be verified by phone.

Comment: I've seen this happen too .. and couldn't figure out how to add it back?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is removing application profile pages, which were previously the way that you added an app to a page.  Now you can use a link, which you can add on your web page for example, to allow people to add the app to their page.  You can also enter the link directly in your browser:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Change YOUR_APP_ID to your numeric app id and YOUR_URL to the secure canvas URL on your app (or you can try http://www.facebook.com/).  More information can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) and [here](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-removing-app-profile-pages-on-feb-1-2012/).